# Verify a ballot triangle

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, combinatorics

A *ballot number*, which we'll label *B*, is the number of ways of arranging the numbers from 1 through B(B+1)/2 into a triangle, such that each row and column is in any increasing order. The first four ballot numbers are:

```
a(0) = 1
a(1) = 1
a(2) = 1
a(3) = 2
```

`a(3)` is 2, which means that there are 2 ways of arranging the numbers from 1 to `3(3+1)/2 = 6` in such a triangle:

```
1          1
2 3    or  2 4
4 5 6      3 5 6
```

See the [OEIS sequence entry](http://oeis.org/A003121) for more details.

Your challenge, given a ballot triangle, is to verify its correctness. If it satisfies the conditions of a ballot triangle (rows and columns increasing), you should output how many *other* ways (excluding the one in the input) there are to arrange the triangle correctly. If the input triangle is incorrectly constructed, you should output nothing.

Trailing newlines are allowed.

### Input

A triangle of numbers, which may or may not be a valid ballot triangle. For example:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6

1
10 5 
9 8 2
7 6 4 3

1
3 2

9
2 11
14 3 5
12 8 1 7
15 13 10 4 6

1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

### Output

If the input is a valid ballot triangle, the remaining number of ways to arrange the same numbers in a valid ballot triangle. If the input is not a valid ballot triangle, nothing. For example, the inputs above produce these outputs (`<nothing>` is a placeholder for an actual empty output):

```
1                     # the same as a(3)-1

<nothing>

<nothing>

<nothing>

33591                 # the same as a(6)-1
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): as usual, lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earliest posted.

Comment: You should probably mention that the columns are also in increasing order.  That confused me until I looked up the OEIS definition.

Comment: Then why isn't `1/4 5/2 3 6` valid?

Comment: Spec fixed - I read the OEIS entry wrong. @ballesta25

Comment: c.c. @LeakyNun ^

Comment: Can we assume that the input will contain the correct numbers, even if not in the correct order?

Comment: @Dennis yes you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;Zµ⁼Ṣ€
ẋÇFŒ!ṁ€⁸ÇÐfL’
```

For valid ballot triangles, run time and memory usage are at least **O(n!)**, where **n** is the number of entries of the triangle. Invalid ones are recognized by crashing, thus printing nothing.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O1rCteKBvOG5ouKCrArhuovDh0bFkiHhuYHigqzigbjDh8OQZkzigJk&input=&args=WzFdLCBbMiwgM10sIFs0LCA1LCA2XQ)

#### Test run

Locally, I was able to verify that **a(4)** is calculated correctly.

```
$ time jelly eun ';Zµ⁼Ṣ€¶ẋÇFŒ!ṁ€⁸ÇÐfL’' '[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]'
11

real    6m9.829s
user    6m7.930s
sys     0m2.579s
```

#### How it works

```
;Zµ⁼Ṣ€         Helper link. Argument: T (triangular array)

 Z             Zip/transpose T.
;              Concatenate the original and the transposed copy.
  µ            Begin a new monadic chain, with the previous result (R) as argument.
    Ṣ€         Sort each array in R.
   ⁼           Test for equality with R.
               This returns 1 if T is a ballot triangle, 0 if not.

ẋÇFŒ!ṁ€⁸ÇÐfL’  Main link. Argument: A (triangular array)

 Ç             Call the helper link with argument A.
ẋ              Repeat A that many times.
               This yields an empty array if A is not a ballot triangle.
  F            Flatten the result.
   Œ!          Generate all permutations of the digits of A.
     ṁ€⁸       Mold each permutation like A, i.e., give it triangular form.
               This crashes if permutation array is empty.
        ÇÐf    Filter; keep permutations for which the helper link returns 1.
           L’  Compute the length and decrement it.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 44 bytes

```
{:{o?}a,?z:2a},?ly+yb:3flw
p~c.:laBtybB,.:1&
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=ezp7bz99YSw_ejoyYX0sP2x5K3liOjNmbHcKcH5jLjpsYUJ0eWJCLC46MSY&input=W1sxXTpbMjozXV0)

This runs in double-exponential time, so for truthy testcases you would need to believe me that it theoretically produces the correct result, for triangles with length greater than or equal to `3`.

You can still test for falsey testcases, those should terminate rather quickly.

Comment: I've had to update the spec - both rows and columns should be increasing. Result of me reading the OEIS entry incorrectly. Sorry if that invalidates your answer!

Comment: @ArtOfCode That was what my answer does all along

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 143 bytes

```
a=>a.some((b,i)=>b.some((c,j)=>c<b[j-1]||i&&c<a[i-1][j]))?'':(f=n=>n<2||n*f(n-1),g=(n,m=f(n*n+n>>1))=>n<2?m:g(--n,m*f(n)/f(n+n+1)),g(a.length))
```

Searches the triangle for an invalid entry and then uses a recursive formulation of the formula in OEIS to calculate the result.

Comment: I've had to update the spec - both rows and columns should be increasing. Result of me reading the OEIS entry incorrectly. Sorry if that invalidates your answer!

Comment: @ArtOfCode No, I was already checking that, but thanks anyway.